# Validate that end date is greater than start date with angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

How do I check/validate in angularjs when click on save button whether end date [textbox] is greater than start date [textbox]?

```
    <form name="myform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>

                <div class="row form-group  ">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2  ">
                        <label class="control-label">From</label>
                        <i id="validationMark">*</i>

                        <input type="date" id="startDate" name="From" ng-model="empModel.from" class="form-control" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'utc'}" />
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <label class="control-label">To</label>
                        <i id="validationMark">*</i>

                        <input type="date" id="endDate" name="To" ng-model="empModel.to" 
                               class="form-control" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'utc'}"  />
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        <span>{{errMessage}}</span>
                    </div>

                </div>

     <button type="button" value="Save" ng-disabled="isDisabledsave"  
             ng-click="myform.$valid && saveCustomer() " id="btnsave" 
             class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save</button>
</form>
```

save button shouldn't call `saveCustomer()` function if `endDate` [textbox] is less than `startDate` [textbox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add some custom validation logic - the only way is to built a directive. Inside a directive you can use something like:

`if($scope.ngModel > $scope.maxValue)
   ctrl.$setValidity("outOfRange", false);`.

But if you just need to forbid the user to fire the click event if the end date  is greater than start date, than you can just write something like:

```
<button type="button" value="Save" ng-disabled="checkDates()"  
         ng-click="saveCustomer() " id="btnsave" 
         class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save</button>
```

and compare dates inside checkDates();

**Update**

The simplest way is just adding:

```
 if($scope.empModel.from > $scope.empModel.to){
    $scope.errMessage="Date is out of range!"
    return;
  }
```

in the start of your saveCustomer() function.

Comment: @WaqasRauf You can also add the date comparing logic inside the the saveCustomer() function, but it will be more explicit to the user if you disable the save button if the dates are wrong.

Comment: this is my POST code
`$scope.saveCustomer = function () {
 $http({ 
method: 'POST', url: '/EmploymentHistory/InsertEmployee', 
data: JSON.stringify($scope.empModel), 
dataType: 'json' }).then(function () { 
console.log($scope.empModel); 
swal("Saved", "Data Imported Successfully", "success") 
GetAllData();
 }); 
};`
 
i dont want to post data if end date is less then start, how i can add validation here and any code you can provide for validation?